# Random characters in WinInet output

Tags: c++, session, output, wininet

I have the following code:

```
#include <wininet.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HINTERNET connect = InternetOpen("MyBrowser",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL, NULL, 0);

   if(!connect){
      cout<<"Connection Failed or Syntax error";
      return 0;
   }

HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrl(connect,"http://shahriar.byethost9.com/com2.html", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE|INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);

   if ( !OpenAddress )
   {
      DWORD ErrorNum = GetLastError();
      cout<<"Failed to open URL \nError No: "<<ErrorNum;
      InternetCloseHandle(connect);
      return 0;
   }

   char DataReceived[4096];
   DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
   while(InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, DataReceived, 4096, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead )
   {
           cout << DataReceived;
   }

   InternetCloseHandle(OpenAddress);
   InternetCloseHandle(connect);

   cin.get();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It grabs the source code of http://shahriar.byethost9.com/com2.html and prints to the console.

The problem is, that the source code of my page is `<h5>paint</h5>`, But the program is printing: `<h5>paint</h5>¥` (the last character is being different each time I'm editing my page source).

After editing my page source it became: `<h5>mspaint</h5>`, but the program was again printing the old source code (`<h5>paint</h5>¥`).

Comment: Either don't assume the buffer null-terminated when you use it or null-terminate it yourself. You have the actual length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to accumulate buffer in such way:

```
cout << std::string(DataReceived, NumberOfBytesRead);
```